# How can I read in files paragraph by paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs, external-files, automation

I have an interesting project here and, while I could do it manually, it seems to me to be an interesting puzzle to automate it.

I have the following structure:

```
./
+- main.tex
|
+- originals/
|  |
|  +- poem1.tex
|  |
|  +- poem2.tex
|
+- translations/
   |
   +- poem1.tex
   |
   +- poem2.tex
```

I'd like to leverage the `parallel` package (or imitate its functionality) and set these poems side-by-side.  How can I read in these files paragraph-by-paragraph as aiming to insert a `\ParallelPar` after each one to align the paragraphs?

Please let me know if there are any more details I can provide.

Since this MWE is rather complicated, a mock-up of the scenario is [provided as a gist](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/11165565):

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/11165565.git
```

Be sure to compile with XeLaTeX.

Comment: I've been working on an algorithm given by http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172856/17423 and I have https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/6da61223fea9906dab91

Comment: My girlfriend is a linguist and for a work of translation, I did something like this for her. I didn't use parallel packages, instead a piece of source code from this website. The fundamentals of the process however, was the same. If you let me know about the following issues, I can modify my code and post it here. First, is linux/mac command line script acceptable? Secondly, are your files always as well formatted as shown in the gist?