# How can I have (or emulate) 'normal' behavior with \ParallelPar when working across pages (on a spread)?

Tags: expl3, parallel

The `parallel` package is able to set parallel columns and align them at `\ParallelPar` tokens:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parallel}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[c]{.45\textwidth}{.45\textwidth}
  \ParallelLText{\lipsum[1]}
  \ParallelRText{\lipsum[3]}
  \ParallelPar

  \ParallelLText{\lipsum[2]}
  \ParallelRText{\lipsum[4]}
  \ParallelPar

  \ParallelLText{\lipsum[5]}
  \ParallelRText{\lipsum[7]}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

When you change the `c` (column) option to `p` (page) however, the alignment is lost.  How can I get the behavior I need?

I am not tied to any particular input format, although I am reading in the translations in [this format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172757/17423).

#### Solution Idea

`\tikzmark` comes to mind, but I've never used it and I'm not sure it's applicable.  The core problem here is that, at the *start* of every paragraph, we need to record the vertical position we are at on the page and save it in some queue.  Say we are typesetting the original text (foreign) on the *verso* (left hand page of the spread) and the translation on the *recto*.  Every paragraph to be set on the verso and recto should be saved in a box.  (I'm assuming that we won't have more than *n* paragraphs `:)`.  *n* is small.; I know there are a limited number of box registers.)  The depth of each box should be set to the maximum of the original and the translation.  This depth is then enqueued.  Boxes continue to be set on the verso in this way until we can't fit the paragraph on the page.  At this point, the boxes destined for recto are placed according the queue of depths.  (Perhaps this queue isn't necessary if we set the depths of the boxes manually, but I'm not sure if this would distort the text a la `graphicx`.)

#### Potential Algorithm

If this isn't supported by the `parallel` package, I've come up with an algorithm that should work—I am just uncomfortable implementing it; I've never worked across pages before.

1. Read text blocks to be aligned into boxes: `\l_original_box` and `\l_translation_box`.
2. Set the depth of each box to the maximum between them.
3. Does `\l_original_box` fit on this page?

   - Yes

     1. Typeset `\l_original_box`.
     2. Place `\l_translation_box` into a queue (a `seq`).
   - No

     1. Start a new page.
     2. Empty queue (of translations) onto the page.
        (Assuming identical page dimensions,
        this should fit on the page since
        the depths are identical to the originals.)
4. Loop until `EOF`.  (See [linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172757/17423).)

*EDIT:* As I'm going through with trying to solve this using the above algorithm ([Work In-Progress](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/6da61223fea9906dab91)), I've noticed that care has to be taken for long lines.  In the `verse` environment, long lines are indented.  (Is there anything like a `parbox` for `expl3`?)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what `c` vs. `p` are supposed to mean?  Is your output supposed to remain on one page?  I am not familiar with this package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The `parallel` is meant for parallel texts (e.g. translations) set side-by-side.  The `c` option sets them in columns on the *same* page, whereas the `p` option sets them on separate pages.  Unfortunately, `\ParallelPar` seems to just be `\newpage` when the `p` option is in effect.  The output is to appear to operate on the entire spread.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/how-do-i-create-6-parallel-texts-aligned-by-paragraph-with-3-texts-on-each-page/131394#131394

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in my comment, I adapted the answer at [How do I create 6 parallel texts aligned by paragraph, with 3 texts on each page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130907/how-do-i-create-6-parallel-texts-aligned-by-paragraph-with-3-texts-on-each-page/131394#131394).  Here, I made it for two columns instead of six, and removed the foreign language support.  I left lines in the table, since I figure it is easier to see where to remove them, than as to where one must add them.  The column width is defined by the length `\colwidth`, currently set to `0.9\textwidth`.

I also just placed simple lipsum in the boxes, as per your MWE, though the approach supports column `\centering` and the `quote` environment.  Column entries will not break in the middle, but will be completely contained on a single page.  The blank lines apparent at the bottom of each entry are an artifact of `\lipsum`, which includes, by default, a new paragraph at the end.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tabindex}
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
  \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\def\colwidth{.9\textwidth}
\newcounter{sptstartrow}
\newcounter{sptendrow}
\newcounter{entries}
\newcounter{pagerows}
\newlength\CurrentTableHeight
\newlength\CurrentRowHeight
\newsavebox\pagerow

\newcommand\newspecialtable{%
  \setcounter{sptendrow}{0}%
  \setcounter{entries}{0}%
  \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
  \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{0pt}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\twoby[2]{%
  \stepcounter{entries}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xf\endcsname{#2}%
  \synctabindex{entries}%
  \sbox{\pagerow}{\formatcol{a}\formatcol{f}}%
  \setlength\CurrentRowHeight{\ht\pagerow+\dp\pagerow}%
  \addtolength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
  \ifdim\CurrentTableHeight>\textheight %
    \makespecialtable[\thepagerows]%
    \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
    \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
    \else\fi%
  \stepcounter{pagerows}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makespecialtable[1][\theentries]{%
  \setcounter{sptstartrow}{\thesptendrow}%
  \addtocounter{sptendrow}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\thesptendrow > \theentries}{\setcounter{sptendrow}{\theentries}}{}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{f}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{a}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\formatcol[1]{%
   \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}X#1\endcsname\strut}%
}

\newcommand\finishspecialtable{\makespecialtable}

\begin{document}
\centering
\newspecialtable
\twoby
  {\lipsum[1]}%
  {\lipsum[3]}%
\twoby
  {\lipsum[2]}%
  {\lipsum[4]}
\twoby
  {\lipsum[5]}%
  {\lipsum[7]}
\twoby
  {\lipsum[1-2]}%
  {\lipsum[3]}%
\twoby
  {\lipsum[2]}%
  {\lipsum[5]}

\finishspecialtable
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]