# Parallel text spacing and numbering

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-numbering, expex, parallel-texts

This post is a follow up to my [previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400372/gloss-on-opposite-page-as-translation). Here, I ask about two issues:

1. *Vertical spacing:* How can I control the vertical spacing/padding in each of the cells? I would like to have full control, up to the point of complete elimination of the vertical spacing (marked with arrows in the figure below).
2. *Numbering:* In addition, I would like for the parallel boxes to have automated numbering (and without producing indented text). In other words, each `twoby` will be automatically numbered in the outer margin.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large, %some options are normalsize,large, Large, LARGE
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont\it,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt
}


%here begins the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172887/121944
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tabindex}
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
  \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\def\colwidth{\textwidth}
\newcounter{sptstartrow}
\newcounter{sptendrow}
\newcounter{entries}
\newcounter{pagerows}
\newlength\CurrentTableHeight
\newlength\CurrentRowHeight
\newsavebox\pagerow

\newcommand\newspecialtable{%
  \setcounter{sptendrow}{0}%
  \setcounter{entries}{0}%
  \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
  \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{0pt}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\twoby[2]{%
  \stepcounter{entries}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xf\endcsname{#2}%
  \synctabindex{entries}%
  \sbox{\pagerow}{\formatcol{a}\formatcol{f}}%
  \setlength\CurrentRowHeight{\ht\pagerow+\dp\pagerow}%
  \addtolength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
  \ifdim\CurrentTableHeight>\textheight %
    \makespecialtable[\thepagerows]%
    \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
    \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
    \else\fi%
  \stepcounter{pagerows}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makespecialtable[1][\theentries]{%
  \setcounter{sptstartrow}{\thesptendrow}%
  \addtocounter{sptendrow}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\thesptendrow > \theentries}{\setcounter{sptendrow}{\theentries}}{}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{f}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{a}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\formatcol[1]{%
   \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}X#1\endcsname\strut}%
}

\newcommand\finishspecialtable{\makespecialtable}

\begin{document}
\centering
\newspecialtable
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

\endgl \xe}%
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

\endgl \xe}%
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}%

\finishspecialtable
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I finally figured out that I can control the vertical spacing with `aboveexskip` and `belowexskip`. Still need help with the automatic numbering of the parallel boxes/paragraphs.

Comment: The spacing can be remedied with a preamble setting, `\lingset{aboveexskip=-2pt, belowexskip=-7pt}`, since the `\exdisplay` introduces the vertical spacing.

Comment: I have revised my answer to address the numbering, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is introduced by the `expex` macro `\exdisplay`.  It can be controlled with a preamble setting, such as`\lingset{aboveexskip=-8pt, belowexskip=-7pt}`.

To address the numbering, in the `\twoby` macro, I added a

```
\llap{\smash{\raisebox{-5pt}{\Large\thetabindex}\hspace{10pt}}}
```

to the left-hand tabular token list and a

```
\rlap{\smash{\raisebox{-5pt}{\hspace{10pt}\Large\thetabindex}}}
```

to the right-hand tabular token list.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{aboveexskip=-8pt, belowexskip=-7pt}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large, %some options are normalsize,large, Large, LARGE
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont\it,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt
}


%here begins the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172887/121944
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{tabindex}
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
  \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\def\colwidth{\textwidth}
\newcounter{sptstartrow}
\newcounter{sptendrow}
\newcounter{entries}
\newcounter{pagerows}
\newlength\CurrentTableHeight
\newlength\CurrentRowHeight
\newsavebox\pagerow

\newcommand\newspecialtable{%
  \setcounter{sptendrow}{0}%
  \setcounter{entries}{0}%
  \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
  \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{0pt}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\twoby[2]{%
  \stepcounter{entries}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xf\endcsname{#2}%
  \synctabindex{entries}%
  \sbox{\pagerow}{\formatcol{a}\formatcol{f}}%
  \setlength\CurrentRowHeight{\ht\pagerow+\dp\pagerow}%
  \addtolength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
  \ifdim\CurrentTableHeight>\textheight %
    \makespecialtable[\thepagerows]%
    \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
    \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
    \else\fi%
  \stepcounter{pagerows}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makespecialtable[1][\theentries]{%
  \setcounter{sptstartrow}{\thesptendrow}%
  \addtocounter{sptendrow}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\thesptendrow > \theentries}{\setcounter{sptendrow}{\theentries}}{}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \llap{\smash{\raisebox{-5pt}{\Large\thetabindex}\hspace{10pt}}}%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{f}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname &
      \rlap{\smash{\raisebox{-5pt}{\hspace{10pt}\Large\thetabindex}}}%
      \vphantom{\formatcol{a}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\formatcol[1]{%
   \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}X#1\endcsname\strut}%
}

\newcommand\finishspecialtable{\makespecialtable}

\begin{document}

\centering
\newspecialtable
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

\endgl \xe}%
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

\endgl \xe}%
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}%

\finishspecialtable
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works well - until I try to change the page size. For example if I use the `geometry` package and turn this into a 5x8 inch book, then formatting issues pop up: `\usepackage[
 paperwidth=5in,
 paperheight=8in,
 inner=0.6in,
 outer=0.6in,
 bindingoffset=0.15in,
 top=0.6in,
 bottom=0.6in,
 twoside]{geometry}`. Can the code be edited somehow so that it scales with shrinking page size?

Comment: @AML I am not sure what you mean.  Obviously, if you change the paper size & margins, it won't look so much like the `book` class anymore.  When I insert the invocation you provide into my code, it compiles, it produces the split table across two pages, with margins in the columns. **Changing the papersize does not shrink the fontsize**.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply I thought it would shrink the fontsize. I just meant that, even though it still compiles for me, the output it no longer very attractive. It's probably something else that has nothing to do with your code. I've got some new troubleshooting to do, but your answer was a good solution so I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to the numbering problem. I'm not quite sure how the numbering relates to the larger document, so you may need to fiddle with resetting the counter or not depending on how the numbers are supposed to increment.

I've used the `array` package to allow pre-column code in tables. It must be loaded before `bidi` which means before `polyglossia` in your example.

I've created a `boxcount` counter which simply counts the boxes. If this needs to be reset every set of boxes, then you will need to add this. As it stands it simply increments throughout the document.  If the numbering resets each `\twoby` then add `\setcounter{boxcount}{0}` to your `\twoby` definition.

I've also changed your fonts to fonts I have.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{array}  % added this package must be loaded before bidi/polyglossia
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM} % change as needed
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large, %some options are normalsize,large, Large, LARGE
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont\it,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt
}


%here begins the code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172887/121944
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{boxcount} % added this counter
\newlength{\boxcountoffset} % added this length
\setlength{\boxcountoffset}{-1em}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{tabindex}
\newtoks\@tabtoks
\newcommand\addtabtoks[1]{%
  \@tabtoks\expandafter{\the\@tabtoks\stepcounter{tabindex}#1}}
\newcommand*\resettabtoks{\@tabtoks{}}
\newcommand*\synctabindex[1]{\setcounter{tabindex}{\value{#1}}}
\newcommand*\printtabtoks{\the\@tabtoks}
\makeatother

\def\colwidth{\textwidth}
\newcounter{sptstartrow}
\newcounter{sptendrow}
\newcounter{entries}
\newcounter{pagerows}
\newlength\CurrentTableHeight
\newlength\CurrentRowHeight
\newsavebox\pagerow

\newcommand\newspecialtable{%
  \setcounter{sptendrow}{0}%
  \setcounter{entries}{0}%
  \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
  \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{0pt}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\twoby[2]{%
  \stepcounter{entries}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xa\endcsname{#1}%
  \expandafter\def\csname entryX\roman{entries}Xf\endcsname{#2}%
  \synctabindex{entries}%
  \sbox{\pagerow}{\formatcol{a}\formatcol{f}}%
  \setlength\CurrentRowHeight{\ht\pagerow+\dp\pagerow}%
  \addtolength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
  \ifdim\CurrentTableHeight>\textheight %
    \makespecialtable[\thepagerows]%
    \setcounter{pagerows}{0}%
    \setlength\CurrentTableHeight{\CurrentRowHeight}%
    \else\fi%
  \stepcounter{pagerows}%
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makespecialtable[1][\theentries]{%
  \setcounter{sptstartrow}{\thesptendrow}%
  \addtocounter{sptendrow}{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\thesptendrow > \theentries}{\setcounter{sptendrow}{\theentries}}{}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xa\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{f}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  % step the counter display and offset it; we're using \refstepcounter here to allow refs
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\refstepcounter{boxcount}\makebox[\boxcountoffset][r]{\theboxcount}}p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{index}{\thesptstartrow}%
  \synctabindex{index}
  \resettabtoks%
  \whiledo{\theindex < \thesptendrow}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \addtabtoks{%
      \csname entryX\roman{tabindex}Xf\endcsname &
      \vphantom{\formatcol{a}}
      \\%
      \hline%
    }%
  }%
  \begin{tabular}{|p{\colwidth}|@{\extracolsep{-\tabcolsep}}l}%
   \hline%
   \printtabtoks%
  \end{tabular}%
}

\newcommand\formatcol[1]{%
   \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{\csname entryX\roman{tabindex}X#1\endcsname\strut}%
}

\newcommand\finishspecialtable{\makespecialtable}

\begin{document}
\centering
\newspecialtable
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

\endgl \xe}%
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd //

\endgl \xe}%
\twoby
  {\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}%
  {\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}%

\finishspecialtable
\end{document}
```

[image: output of first page]