# Parallel texts adding page breaks after each paragraph

Tags: parallel

I'm new to LaTeX (I'm working with pdfLaTeX) and have found such great stuff here so far. This is my first time asking a question here so if I've left anything out of the question or the MWE or included anything I shouldn't have, let me know and I'll edit.

I'm working on a bilingual Latin/English edition of a novel using the parallel package, but every time I want the text to start a new paragraph, it starts a new page instead. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

```
documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}[utf8]
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\newcommand{\bi}[2]{
\selectlanguage{latin}\ParallelLText{#1}\selectlanguage{english}\ParallelRText{#2}
\ParallelPar
}

\chapter{Chapter Title}
\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
\bi{
Paragraph 1 in Latin
}
{
Paragraph 1 in English
}
\bi{
Paragraph 2 in Latin
}
{
Paragraph 2 in English
}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I would say this is the normal behavior of the `p` option of `Parallel` environment by looking really quickly into the package code. I would suggest you use another option.

Comment: AH! Well, that makes things much clearer. I was assuming that \ParallelPar would just line things up by paragraph, not by page. Do you have any suggestions for other options? (Also, if you want to make this an answer then, unless somebody else comes along and it turns out there's a way with parallel to do it, I'll gladly accept.)

Comment: You might take a look at the package `paracol`.  I haven't used it myself, but the documentation looks like paragraphs are parallel, so if they're not the same length there is blank space, but they continue on the same page if there's room.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using reledmac and reledpar and adapting @Steven B. Segletes 's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172856/how-can-i-have-or-emulate-normal-behavior-with-parallelpar-when-working-acr/172887#172887